# Prestashop Smarty Cache css file path error 404

Tags: css, caching, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have console error -> file not found 404 -> this is a cache css file with path error.
/themes/default-bootstrap/cache/v_37_aed4c0aa657ac1142332692bc74511ed_all.css

Using inspector i have added "prestashop" and now Prestashop css is ok.
prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/cache/v_37_aed4c0aa657ac1142332692bc74511ed_all.css

Notice Prestashop js file path is correct

How can i correct this error ?
[path error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuZpO.png)
[path ok using inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJGsl.png)

Comment: same error for me, only for css cache, shop configuration is correct, seems a prestashop bug

Comment: It is a prestashop v1.6.1.5 bug (when shop base dir is different from root '/', the minified css path is wrong because it ignores the base dir setting), it should be solved in prestashop v.1.6.1.6

Answer (score 4):

Login to admin panel and visit *Advance parameters --> Performance*. On top right corner there is button *Clear Cache*, by clicking that cache will be cleared and your site should work I think.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: it will be better if you disable cache and then check again.

Comment: i have disabled cache and now is ok. But when i set cache again i have the same error.

Comment: Are you able to share your site link?

Comment: This is a local host installation.

Comment: It seems a smarty cache bug. There is an error subdomain path.

Comment: This happen only cache css file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You have a link screen error. Do you need anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have configured shop wrongly. In back office go to `Preferences -> SEO& URLs` and do the following changes.

> Shop URL: 192.168.1.128:8080
>
> Base : /preshtashop/

Then clear your cache and enable it and look again.

Comment: As you wrote my shop is configured ok.

Comment: Please, notice my images and you will see that javascript cache path is ok and css is wrong. Without caches my Prestashop works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Prestashop v1.6.1.5 bug, it should be solved in v.1.6.1.6

See the changelog (https://www.prestashop.com/en/developers-versions/changelog/1.6.1.6-stable):

```
[-] FO : (c0ee6b7) Fix CSS 404 when using subdirectory
```